# Turn off tablet desktop noises

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow

I'm sure this is pretty basic but its driving me nuts. I have a new tablet (cheap one) with Android 6.0 on it.  When I touch an icon on the desktop I get a vib and noise. The only way I've found to shut this off is to turn off all sound and vibrations - is there a better way of just stopping the touch noises.  I've found how to turn off the keyboard noises, but not the "icon" noises.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can get an option in your settings of haptic feedback. Turn it off and ping back if it was worked